# SAT #1 Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: arithmetic

1. Every Sunday Graham jogs 3 miles. For the rest of the week, each day he jogs 1 mile more than the preceding day. How many miles does Greg jog in 2 weeks?
   (A) 42;
   (B) 63;
   (C) 84;
   (D) 98;
   (E) 117.

Comment: I don't really jog, sorry.

Comment: @gregkow haha, let me edit the question. It now says Graham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of a finite arithmetic sequence is the average of the first and the last term, times the number of terms. In this case we have (for each week) a seven-term arithmetic sequence where the first term is $3$ and the last term is $9$ (since each day he jogs one more mile, so on the following Saturday, six days later, he will jog $9$ miles). Thus the number of miles jogged per week is $\frac{3+9}{2}\cdot 7=42$. The total number of miles jogged in $2$ weeks is then $2\cdot 42 = 84$.

It's also easy enough to calculate $2\cdot (3+4+5+6+7+8+9)=84$ directly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the week starts on the Sunday, he jogs for $3$, then he jogs for $4,5,6,7,8,9$. Sum these up, you get $42$. Multiplied by $2$ weeks, we get $84$.